# Setting the environment variable https_proxy gives different behavior compared to setting proxies in botocore.config when listing cloudfront distros

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, proxy, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

The following code, with setting proxy as environment variable, works as expected, thus `cloudfront_client.list_distributions()` returns cloudfront distributions list in json format.

```
if configuration['egress_proxy_enabled']:
        proxy_host = f"{configuration['egress_proxy_host']}:{configuration['egress_proxy_port']}"
        os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = proxy_host
        client = boto_session.client('cloudfront')
```

While the following code, with proxy set in boto3 function seems not setting it correctly, because `list_distributions()` method times out:

```
if configuration['egress_proxy_enabled']:
        proxy_host = f"{configuration['egress_proxy_host']}:{configuration['egress_proxy_port']}"
        client = boto_session.client('cloudfront', config=botocore.config.Config(proxies={'https': proxy_host}))
```

What may be the reason of such discrepancy?